# Generate options by mapping over array of objects with react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, react-select

I'm using `react-select` to create a Select option in my `create-react-app` and am trying to map over an array of objects to generate the options. My app loads fine but when I click on the Select I get this error: `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I'm passing the data to the component via props which is working fine, and the data is structured like this:

```
const guests = [
    {
        name: 'Kait',
        plus: true,
        plusName: 'Kitty'
    },
    {
        name: 'Séanin',
        plus: true,
        plusName: 'Guest'
    }
]
```

And here's the Select component:

```
<Select
   value={selectedOption}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   options={
      this.props.guests.map((guest, index) => {
         return {
            label: guest,
            value: guest,
            key: index
         }
      })
   }
/>
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: I guess the code looks fine. Are you sure you're not displaying guests array anywhere?

Answer (score 5):

[Sung M. Kim‘s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55173797/6612182) is correct, but there is an easier way to use your attributes as label and value without remapping your options array.

Using the props `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` you can keep your object mappings. Both accept a function that gets a single option as an argument and returns the value or label from the appropriate object property as string.

```
<Select
    options={this.props.guests}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    { /* Couldn't find a value in your structure, so I used name again */ }
    getOptionValue=((option) => option.name}
    { ... }
/>
```

See [documentation](https://react-select.com/advanced#replacing-builtins) for more.

Answer (score 2):

You probably will have to generate the array before rendering the component

```
const options = this.props.guests.map((guest, index) => {
     return {
        label: guest.name,
        value: guest,
        key: index
     }
})
<Select
   value={selectedOption}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   options={options}
/>
```

Edit:

is because you are passing an object in the label field. You should pass a String instead

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the label is set as `guest` (an object) not as `guest.name` (a string).

Making following change will work.

```
<Select
   value={selectedOption}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   options={
      this.props.guests.map((guest, index) => {
         return {
-            label: guest,
+            label: guest.name
            value: guest,
            key: index
         }
      })
   }
/>
```

You can try it out in the sandbox link below.
[image: Edit so.answer.55173409]